# How to post multiple files to server one by one (due to server side restriction) using javascript from html input type file control

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I have some server side restriction.
I want to read file to server one by one using javascript, in such a way that second file will post only after the response from previous file is received.

I have a multiple file upload in my webform as below:

```
<form id="frmSearchByC2V" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="file" style="width:50px" type="file" name="c2vFile" id="txtSearchC2V" disabled  onchange="locateFiles();" />      
</form>
```

In my javascript i have code something like

```
<script>
    function locateFiles()
    {
        var fileChooserControl = document.getElementById("txtSearchC2V");
        var selectedFileLength = fileChooserControl.files!=null?fileChooserControl.files.length:1;
        for(var i=0; i < selectedFileLength; i++)
        {              
            document.forms["frmSearchByC2V"].action="locateFiles.html;
            //Ajax call to submit the form
            AIM.submit(document.getElementById("frmSearchByC2V"), {'onStart' : function(){return true;}, 'onComplete' : function(response){
                            loadSearchTargetGrid(response);
            }}); 
            document.getElementById("frmSearchByC2V").submit();
        }
    }

    function loadSearchTargetGrid(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that whenever i post multiple file using window browser button. Everytime a received the same file to server. eg i choose file.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt and submit the form via javascript, i receive file3.txt in every request i made to the server.

Please provide the solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YUI, you can use the `Uploader` utility. `Uploader` will upload each file in its own POST request and additionally you can set its `simLimit` attribute to `1` so that it only makes one request at a time. See: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/.